# Select copy of item from array in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, copy, lodash

I have function that takes array of items as parameter.
In function I want to find one item and modify its property.

```
const defaultGroup = find(groupedCustomFields, group => group.name === DEFAULT_GROUP); //[find][1] - it's `lodash` function
defaultGroup.fields = defaultGroup.fields.filter(f => !f.isGroupEditable);
```

This code select item from collection (first matched item) and updates object property.

As result my input collection is also updated (updated finded item in it). 
I don't want to do this. So I think I should modify copy of this item.

What is the best way to do it?

```
const defaultGroup = find(groupedCustomFields, group => group.name === DEFAULT_GROUP),
copyOfDefGroup = Object.assign({}, defaultGroup);
```

Is this code preferable for this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.assign` is fine in my opinion for copying objects.
Extra tip - To copy an array, `array.slice()` is the easiest way

Comment: Note that [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Description) returns a shallow copy of the array. The object references inside the array, however, refer to the same object of the copied array.

Answer (score 1):

Because you added "TypeScript" in your tags, I wanted to mention that as of TypeScript 2.1 you have "Object Spreading".

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#object-spread-and-rest

So you can easily copy an object (or merge multiple) like this:

```
let copy = { ...original };
```